# no implementation for `dyn std::error::Error == dyn std::error::Error`

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-cargo, rust-tokio, actix-web

I have an async function that returns a struct after all the web parsing is done. When running the tests I'm getting the error: `` no implementation for `dyn std::error::Error == dyn std::error::Error` `` . How can I solve this or what am I doing wrong?

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct ParsingResult<'a> {
    title: &'a str,
    content: String,
}
impl<'a> ParsingResult<'a> {
    pub fn new(title: &'a str, content: String) -> Self {
        ParsingResult { title, content }
    }
}
pub async fn yahoo_template<'a>(
    link_to_the_article: &str,
) -> Result<ParsingResult<'a>, Box<dyn error::Error>> {
    let resp = reqwest::get(link_to_the_article).await?.text().await?;

    let mut final_res: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    Document::from(resp.as_str())
        .find(Name("a"))
        .filter_map(|n| n.attr("href"))
        .for_each(|x| {
            if x.contains("http") || x.contains("https") {
                final_res.push(String::from(x));
            }
        });
    // println!("{:?}", final_res);
    Ok(ParsingResult::new("Title", String::from("String")))
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod templates_tests {
    use super::*;
    #[tokio::test]
    async fn make_it_work() {
        let expected = Ok(ParsingResult::new("Title", String::from("String")));
        assert_eq!(
            expected,
            yahoo_template("https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_de_Maupassant").await
        );
    }
}
```

Error output:

```
error[E0277]: can't compare `dyn std::error::Error` with `dyn std::error::Error`
  --> src/scraper/scraping_templates.rs:47:3
   |
47 | /         assert_eq!(
48 | |             expected,
49 | |             yahoo_template("https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_de_Maupassant").await
50 | |         );
   | |_________^ no implementation for `dyn std::error::Error == dyn std::error::Error`
   |
   = help: the trait `PartialEq` is not implemented for `dyn std::error::Error`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `PartialEq` for `Box<dyn std::error::Error>`
   = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `PartialEq` for `Result<scraping_templates::ParsingResult<'_>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`
   = note: this error originates in the macro `assert_eq` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: Please always post the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: Also, do not just post all of your code here. Please reduce the problem to a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ohh, i see, my bad, I've updated the question, you can see the error from cargo test. Thank you

Comment: [Do not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error comes from the `assert_eq!()` invocation in `async fn make_it_work()`.

This assertion attempts to compare two `Result<ParsingResult<'a>, Box<dyn error::Error>>` values for equality.  `Result` only implements equality comparison when the types for the `Ok` and `Err` variants can be compared for equality with themselves.  This means that `ParsingResult<'a>` must implement `PartialEq` for itself (it does due to your `#[derive]`) and `Box<dyn error::Error>` must also implement `PartialEq` -- but `Box`, like `Result`, only implements equality comparison when the value it contains can be compared for equality, and `error::Error` doesn't require `PartialEq` (and if it did then `error::Error` wouldn't be object-safe anyway, so you wouldn't be able to use `dyn`).

All that to say, the `Err` case can't be tested for equality, and so this particular instantiation of `Result` can't be tested for equality either.  The compiler doesn't care that you're checking an `Ok` value, which means that it won't ever have to compare the `Err` variant values, it just sees two `Result`s being compared for equality and can't find a `PartialEq` implementation.

To work around this, you can modify your assertion:

```
let expected = ParsingResult::new("Title", String::from("String"));
let actual = yahoo_template("https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_de_Maupassant").await;

assert_eq!(actual.ok(), Some(expected));
```

The `.ok()` method turns a `Result<V, E>` into an `Option<V>` by mapping `Ok(v)` to `Some(v)` and `Err(_)` to `None`.  This effectively discards the error, bypassing the need for the error type to have an equality comparison implementation.

---

If you want to retain the error information for display in case the test fails, consider mapping the error to a type that does have an equality operation.  For example, just map the error to the stringified debug representation.  This will turn the `Err` variant into `String`, which obviously does provide equality comparison.

```
let expected = ParsingResult::new("Title", String::from("String"));
let actual = yahoo_template("https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_de_Maupassant").await;

assert_eq!(actual.map_err(|e| format!("{:?}", e)), Ok(expected));
```